# How to only mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

jest unit test question here. If I am testing function A, and function A uses function B,

```
import { funcB } = require('./FileB');

const funcA = () => {
  const someData = funcB();
}
```

Does this mean that, in my unit test file testing `funcA`, in order to mock `funcB`, do i HAVE to import the function to mock it? which means the file wouldn't use that function but simply there for mocking purposes or do I have to mock the entire module in which `funcB` lives on and mock the implementation of that single function?

my goal here is, I dont want every single test in my unit test file to have `funcB` mocked, I only want it mocked on some test but not all while testing `funcA`.

So if i have 4 test and 3 of them need it mocked but 2 need its actuall implementation, whats a best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution - use `spyOn` and `mockRestore` for following implementation:

```js
export const funcB = () => {
  console.log('original implementation of B')
  return 42;
}
```

```js
import { funcB } from './fileb';

export const funcA = () => {
  const someData = funcB();
  return someData;
}
```

```js
import * as fileB from "../funcab/fileb";
import { funcA } from "../funcab/filea";

describe('testing 1...2...3...', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(fileB, 'funcB');

  afterEach(() => {
    spy.mockRestore();
  })

  it('will test with mocked funcB', () => {
    spy.mockReturnValue(1);
    expect(funcA()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('will test without mocked funcB', () => {
    expect(funcA()).toEqual(42);
  })
})
```

Here is a post about [Jest mock and spy — mockClear vs mockReset vs mockRestore](https://marek-rozmus.medium.com/jest-mock-and-spy-mockclear-vs-mockreset-vs-mockrestore-f52395581950). I hope you'll find it usefull.

Answer for comment - do you mean sth like this?

```js
const mockFuncB = jest.fn();
jest.mock("../funcab/fileb", () => ({
  funcB: () => mockFuncB(),
}));
```

then the test would look like:

```js
it('will test with mocked funcB', () => {
  mockFuncB.mockReturnValue(1);
  expect(funcA()).toEqual(1);
});
```

Comment: thank you, do you know if there is anyway to mock out everything else in that module but leave the one function i wanna spy on alone? some stuff about this module loads external deps but i only wanna spy/test/mock one thing on it

Comment: Updated the answer regarding your comment. If this is not what you want, please explain in more detail.